# Angular / ExpressJS / RestFul Security

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, express

Currently I'm building an application with Angular, ExpressJS and Mongodb. Short question: let angular reach (GET/POST/DELETE) '/api' (expressJS+Mongodb supported by restful). But make api private so only angular client side can use the api.

Long Question: 
- **Angular client side**: http://localhost:3000,
- **Express + restful**:   http://localhost:3005/api,
- **Apache proxy to localhost**: domain.com -> localhost:3000

My Angular client side is doing GET/POST requests to the backend api. This api should be only reachable for the client side running on port 3000. REST Clients requests should be blocked by express server. Everything is working behind apache2. Apache reverse proxies the client side only. The client side and server side are separated from each other. How can I make the server side private only, not reachable from outside?

So far I tried:

- Whitelist CORS localhost:3000 and block all other, will not work because of reversed proxy. Resulting in blocked by CORS.
- Csrf token cookie, could be manipulated, grab value and set by headers.
- Using a login is not an option, since there are no users.

-Maybe I only need a push in right direction, I'm happy with any answer.

**EDIT**: *I found out that my api is not reachable behind the proxy. You can't make calls to localhost:3005/api because apache is proxy-ing everything to localhost:3000. Am I right about this? Is it 99% safe?*

Comment: It's difficult to ascertain what your actual question is. The fact there isn't a question mark (?) anywhere doesn't help.

Comment: EDIT: "How can I make the server side private only, not reachable from outside?"

Comment: I don't think there is any other option but to create a session token.

Comment: I read many posts about session token not ready for production since it will leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so good way to approach this is to build your api integrated with an OAuth server. After that, you can simply generated a client id and put that somewhere in your front-end to be accessible. You front-end will then be able to request and consume tokens which will grant permission to access data.

This has the added benefit of being able to support both login and selective access based on client id should the need arise in future. Here's an interesting article you can check out.

http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/07/02/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-oauth2-server/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this out. But will this work behind the reserved proxy? Also this seems like its 1 global project and not 2 separated projects.